# Replacing values across two tables in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table ts1 in mySQL composed by column1,...,column100 and a table ts2 composed by column1,...,column100. I want to replace the values in column1,...,column90 of ts1 with those in ts2 without listing the names of all columns. Any idea?

Comment: I would question the design of such a table. Seems like the table creator confused records with columns. But why don't you use a data editing tool and copy/paste values from one table to the other?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to mySQL. One idea could be taking columns1-90 from ts2 and columns 91-100 from ts2 and merging them in a new table ts3. How can I do this?

Comment: So,do you want to replace the values of rows for the first 90 columns of ts1? Also, what do you mean by "without listing the names of all columns"?

Comment: I would seriously consider redesigning your table. How many rows do your tables t1 and t2 have? Each has one record only? If not, how did you imagine to decide which one should be joined with which?

Comment: @KostasMitsarakis Yes exactly; by "without listing the names of all columns" I mean without the necessity of writing column1, column2, column3, ...., column 90. Is there any shortcut in mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign values and columns dynamically so you need to use variables in conjunction with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`.

- First you make a CONCAT for the first 90 columns of the table `ts1` and you store them in variable `@sql1`.
- Then you make a same CONCAT for the last 10 columns of the table `ts2` and you store them in variable `@sql2`.
- Finally you merge those two values into a SELECT statement that will give you the INSERT values when it will be executed.

Note that this solution is valid only if your tables `ts1`, `ts2` have the same number of rows and have a proper column to get joined.

Also note that if you try this in phpMyAdmin it will not run but if you open your MySQL console and copy & paste it, it will be executed correctly.

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SET @sql1 = NULL;
SET @sql2 = NULL;

SET @t1 = 'ts1';
SET @t2 = 'ts2';
SET @t3 = 'ts3';

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(@t1, '.' ,COLUMN_NAME)) INTO @sql1
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = @t1 AND table_schema = 'a' AND ORDINAL_POSITION <= 90;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(@t2, '.', COLUMN_NAME)) INTO @sql2
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = @t2 AND table_schema = 'a' AND ORDINAL_POSITION > 90;

SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ', @t3, ' (', ' SELECT ', @sql1, ', ', @sql2, ' FROM ', @t1, ' INNER JOIN ', @t2, ' ON ', @t1, '.col1 = ', @t2, '.col1 );');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```